# Starting out with CISCO

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have decided to gain some further knowledge of routing, VPN, VLAN, etc.

Am using GNS3 to simulate various situations.  I have a connected set of LANs, the core is running OSPF and BGP. I have a connected OSPF network.

Core: OSPF area 0 - 172.16.1.x
LAN: OSPF area 100 - 10.0.100.x

I can ping out through a cloud to the world from any 172.16 interface but not from the 10.0 interfaces within the LAN100 area.

I have a default route from any 172.16 out to the cloud interface (192.168.122.1) and the 10.0 LAN devices have a 'default-information originate' route to the 10.0 border router.  Even though I can ping from the inside BDR interfaces to any other BDR interfaces on the same router, I am unable to ping out to 172.

Given that I have default routes out, can reach 172.16.1.30 from 10.0.100.31, can reach 172.16.1.29 from 172.16.1.30, why not from 10 to 172?

I couldn't find any previous question that seemed appropriate.

APOLOGIES for the layout. I tried again and again to get this as plain, pre-formatted text but it ain't happening. I put '>' in, I tried pasting and clicking '"', I tried list, I tried indent. I gave up. Life seems too short :)

```
Gateway of last resort is 172.16.1.29 to network 0.0.0.0

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 2 subnets
C       1.1.2.1 is directly connected, Loopback1

C       1.1.1.10 is directly connected, Loopback0

     172.16.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets

C       172.16.1.28 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0

     10.0.0.0/27 is subnetted, 3 subnets

C       10.0.100.64 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet3/0

C       10.0.100.32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet2/0

C       10.0.100.0 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet1/0

S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 172.16.1.29
```

boughrd router

```
Gateway of last resort is 172.16.1.29 to network 0.0.0.0

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 2 subnets

C       1.1.2.1 is directly connected, Loopback1

C       1.1.1.10 is directly connected, Loopback0

     172.16.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets

C       172.16.1.28 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0

     10.0.0.0/27 is subnetted, 3 subnets

C       10.0.100.64 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet3/0

C       10.0.100.32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet2/0

C       10.0.100.0 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet1/0

S*   0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 172.16.1.29
```

IOSvR5 router

```
Gateway of last resort is 192.168.122.1 to network 0.0.0.0

B*    0.0.0.0/0 [200/0] via 192.168.122.1, 00:38:50

      1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 6 subnets

O        1.1.1.1 [110/2] via 172.16.1.25, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/2

O        1.1.1.2 [110/2] via 172.16.1.22, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/1

O IA     1.1.1.3 [110/3] via 172.16.1.22, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/1

O        1.1.1.4 [110/3] via 172.16.1.17, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/0

O        1.1.1.5 [110/2] via 172.16.1.17, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/0

C        1.1.1.6 is directly connected, Loopback0

      172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 12 subnets, 2 masks

O        172.16.1.0/30 [110/2] via 172.16.1.25, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/2

                       [110/2] via 172.16.1.22, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/1

O        172.16.1.4/30 [110/2] via 172.16.1.22, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/1

O        172.16.1.8/30 [110/3] via 172.16.1.22, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/1

                       [110/3] via 172.16.1.17, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/0

O        172.16.1.12/30 [110/2] via 172.16.1.17, 00:39:21, GigabitEthernet0/0

C        172.16.1.16/30 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0

L        172.16.1.18/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0

C        172.16.1.20/30 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1

L        172.16.1.21/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1

C        172.16.1.24/30 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/2

L        172.16.1.26/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/2

C        172.16.1.28/30 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/3

L        172.16.1.29/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/3

B     192.168.122.0/24 [200/0] via 1.1.1.1, 00:38:50
```

Comment: Can we see a picture of the simulation topology?

Comment: I tried to paste it in and because I am new user the site suggested there would be a link to the image.  If that is not there then this site really sucks.  No formatting, no image. What the frik am I doing :P

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc4cT.png

Comment: just use the traceroute to see where did the issue happen, and check the interface, the protocol.Check if the OSPF neighbors are normal. As usual, it is a route issue. I like to use `traceroute`.

Comment: Traceroute only goes as far as the 10.0.100 gate and no further, which is just one hop.  I am wondering (why I don't know) if it is something to do with routing between two OSPF areas but with a direct route between the two I don't see why this shoudl be a problem.